# How to properly set up new Node project with Yarn and its `pnp` strategy?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg-v2

I'm thoroughly following Yarn's installation and usage manual, but immediately stumble upon this error:

```
enc@alpha:~/Projects/personal/yarn-test/src$ node app.js 
node:internal/process/esm_loader:97
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'express' imported from /home/enc/Projects/personal/yarn-test/src/app.js
Did you mean to import express-npm-4.18.2-bb15ff679a-3c4b9b0768.zip/node_modules/express/index.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:889:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:938:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

For Node version management I use `fnm` utility and trying to make new setup with `Node.js v18.15.0`:

```
enc@alpha:~/Projects/personal/yarn-test/src$ fnm list
* v16.3.0
* v18.15.0 default
* system
```

And `3.4.1 version of Yarn`:

```
enc@alpha:~/Projects/personal/yarn-test/src$ yarn -v
3.4.1
```

`package.json:`

```
{
  "name": "yarn-test",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./src/app.js",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.4.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongodb": "^5.1.0"
  }
}
```

For test I use the simplest `app.js` file. I've made new project with familiar 'npm' manager and it works perfectly with next code:

```
import express from 'express';
console.log('Working!');
const app = express();
```

But when i'm trying to run it with `node ./src/app.js` from yarn's project folder, the error described above appears. What do I do wrong?

Comment: in your start script maybe you can use `yarn node ./src/app.js`. not totally sure if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I've managed with a lot of reading the same question throughout the Internet.